# redisplay user input

Tags: java, jsp

how can I redisplay user input, sinc the values of `<input type="checkBox" name="group" value=${grp.groupNo}>` is defined at run time?  how can I use `${param}` here to make comparison with unknown values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of checkboxes (and radiobuttons) you'd like to set the `checked` attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group" value="${grp.groupNo}" ${grp.groupNo == param.group ? 'checked' : ''}>
```

The conditional operator `?:` in EL will print `checked` when the condition is true. So it will then end up like follows in generated HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group" value="1" checked>
```

Comment: that's work if u know group number, but in my case groups numbers are define when i render the jsp,since i bring them form db, so i cannot make that explicit comparison.

Comment: Then use EL instead as in my updated answer. Your initial question was pretty unclear so that I just showed a simplified example.